# I need a Crank Reccomendation. Single Speed, BB30

Tags: alfine

I am undertaking my first build from a frame. I bought a used Cannondale Synapse Alloy Disc frame. It's quite nice.
I am installing new brakes, cables and everything else. 
Also, I am dead set on using an Internal Gear hub in the rear, and have selected a Shimano Alfine 8. My problem is finding a Single Chain Ring crank that will work with it. The frame says BB30 on it and has a BB30 BB installed. It's got two press fit bearings installed and each bearing has a clip ring on the inside of the bearing. The bike only has a couple of hundred miles on it so the bearings look new.
I cannot seem to find a crank that is compatible with this BB30 setup, and I do not know if I can out a different BB in this frame. My local bike shops are swamped this time of year, so no help for months (I live in upstate NY so we have a short season). I'd appreciate any help or advice!! Thanks, Dave

Comment: Crank designs that will fit: BB30, BB386 EVO, standard 24mm external-type, Specialized OSBB, BBright. BB30 is an SRAM standard, so many SRAM cranks will fit.

Comment: The good, clean way of doing what you're trying to do here is run an eccentric BB30 adapter so you don't have to resort to a tensioner or magic ratio. There are BB30 eccentrics available that provide either a threaded shell you can put any ISO BB into, or ones that take a crank with a 24mm spindle directly, ie the adapter is also your BB.

Comment: One thing to consider is that road frames have 130mm spacing and the Alfine hub is 135mm wide.

Comment: Thankfully, the frame is 135, I guess because it is a disc brake frame. I'm thinking about an FSA adapter, which people have expressed good experience with. Seems like a pretty straightforward installation, so long as I can get a decent chain line.

Comment: Are you willing to use a 10 speed chain? SRAM 1x road cranksets come in BB30, but you'll have to deal with higher price and faster wear than a standard 1/8" single speed chain.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in some comments, many cranks will fit. You need a 30mm width spindle crank. BB30, a cannondale staple crank size, is just this.

You can use a 24mm crank with an adapter. Some cannondale riders I know have all their bikes set up like this. I don't really like it. Extraneous parts and more weight. The advantages are serviceability and possibly less creaking, though I've never had a problem with this. It's more serviceable because you have a threaded bottom bracket that's easier to remove. (Most home mechanics don't have the proper bearing pusher/pullers to remove and reseat BB30 bearings correctly, though I've seen it done).

Sram is what I use in my cannondale and I'd recommend it. I'm sure BB30 cranks from other manufactures are just as good. The bike came with an FSA crank, but I didn't care for it because it is comparatively heavier and less stiff than my Sram Red BB30 crank.

Here are some pics of what it looks like in the frame:
[image]

[image]

[image]